# Bing maps rout on window phone Emulator through proxy

Tags: windows-phone-7

I used the below given code to draw the route on Bing Maps. It works fine on emulator when the system is connected to internet directly. But when i am under my company's proxy on the second last line of code it throws exception saying: **Proxy authorization required : 407**

```
BingMaps.RouteService.RouteServiceClient routeService = new BingMaps.RouteService.RouteServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IRouteService");
            BingMaps.RouteService.RouteRequest RouteReq = new BingMaps.RouteService.RouteRequest();
            RouteReq.Credentials = new BingMaps.RouteService.Credentials();
            RouteReq.Credentials.ApplicationId = ((ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider)Map.CredentialsProvider).ApplicationId;


            RouteOptions rOptions = new RouteOptions();
            rOptions.Mode = TravelMode.Driving;
            rOptions.Optimization = RouteOptimization.MinimizeDistance;
            RouteReq.Options = rOptions;
            RouteReq.Options.RoutePathType = BingMaps.RouteService.RoutePathType.Points;

            // Set the waypoints of the route to be calculated using the Geocode Service results stored in the geocodeResults variable.
            RouteReq.Waypoints = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Waypoint>();
            foreach (Waypoint wp in WPList)
            {
                RouteReq.Waypoints.Add(wp);
            }
            //routeService.ClientCredentials = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials( new NetworkCredential("461167", "July@2012", "india");
            routeService.CalculateRouteAsync(RouteReq);
            routeService.CalculateRouteCompleted += new EventHandler<CalculateRouteCompletedEventArgs>(RouteService_CalculateRouteCompleted);
```

I understand that i need to set proxy but, i am not able to find out how. Because RouteService is not configured accept the proxy credentials.

Also internet is working fine on the emulator, i have also set the proxy credentials on the emulator.

Please suggest how to do it or it is not possible because it is not using the proxy credentials of emulator and not even the credentials stored on the system.

Comment: Are you running the emulator behind a proxy that uses authentication?

Comment: yes.I am under my companies proxy and it requires authentication.